# Docker : Could not resolve host: github.com - for go get ./

Tags: github, go, docker

When running my Dockerfile I need to grab dependencies. This is done using `go get ./...`.

However when doing `docker build -t test .` it hangs at the go get command.

#### here is the error message

> exec go get -v -d
>
> github.com/gorilla/mux (download)
>    cd .; git clone https://github.com/gorilla/mux /go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux Cloning into
>   '/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux'... fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/gorilla/mux/': Could not resolve host: github.com
>   package github.com/gorilla/mux: exit status 128

#### here is the dockerfile

```
FROM golang

# Create a directory inside the container to store all our application and then make it the working directory.
RUN mkdir -p /go/src/example-app
WORKDIR /go/src/example-app

# Copy the example-app directory (where the Dockerfile lives) into the container.
COPY . /go/src/example-app

# Download and install any required third party dependencies into the container.
RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install
RUN go get ./...

# Set the PORT environment variable inside the container
ENV PORT 8080

# Expose port 8080 to the host so we can access our application
EXPOSE 8080

# Now tell Docker what command to run when the container starts
CMD ["go-wrapper", "run"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're doing that via ssh on another machine. Check if it has a dns server in your `/etc/network/interfaces`. It should look somehow like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.9
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1 8.8.4.4
```

DNS servers that "always" work are `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`, both provided by Google. If that doesn't resolve your problem, you should check your internet connection for other misconfigurations, but first try this.